# DOMPDF not working on live server in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

I'm using codeigniter framework and dompdf to generate pdf . It works totally fine on localhost but shows 500 error when on live server. I've tried debugging but it doesnt shows any errors in error_log file. Here is the code of the function generate_pdf.

```
 public function generate_pdf($content, $name = 'download.pdf', $output_type = null, $footer = null, $margin_bottom = null, $header = null, $margin_top = null, $orientation = 'P')
{
    $this->load->library('pdf');
    $html = '';
    if (is_array($content)) {
        foreach ($content as $page) {
            $html .= $header?'<header>'.$header.'</header>':'';
            $html .= '<footer>'.($footer?$footer.'<br><span class="pagenum"></span>' : '<span class="pagenum"></span>').'</footer>';
            $html .= '<body><div class="page">'.$page['content'].'</div></body>';
        }
    } else {
        $html .= $header?'<header>'.$header.'</header>' : '';
        $html .= $footer?'<footer>'.$footer.'</footer>' : '';
        $html .= $content;
    }
    $this->pdf->set_option('isPhpEnabled', true);
    $this->pdf->set_option('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true);
    $this->pdf->set_option('isRemoteEnabled', true);
    $this->pdf->set_option('enable_html5_parser', TRUE);
    // $this->pdf->set_option("DOMPDF_ENABLE_HTML5PARSER", true);

    // $this->pdf->loadHtml($html);
    $html = preg_replace('/>\s+</', '><', $html);
    // $this->pdf->loadHtml($contents);
    $this->pdf->loadHtml($html);
    // $dompdf->load_html($html);
     
    $this->pdf->setPaper('A4', ($orientation == 'P' ? 'portrait' : 'landscape'));
   
    // $dompdf->set_option('enable_html5_parser', TRUE);
    $this->pdf->render();
    // $this->pdf->stream("dompdf_out.pdf", array("Attachment" => true));
    // exit(0);
    
    if ($output_type == 'S') {
        // $output = $dompdf->output();
        $output = $this->pdf->output();
        write_file('assets/uploads/' . $name, $output);
        return 'assets/uploads/' . $name;
    } 
    else {
        $this->pdf->stream($name);
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is the error which i get:

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: ParseError

Message: syntax error, unexpected '='

Filename: /app/third_party/dompdf/src/Dompdf.php

Line Number: 356
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Dompdf 0.8.5, This is your Exception's line

```
[$this->protocol, $this->baseHost, $this->basePath] = Helpers::explode_url($file);
```

If this works on localhost but not on live server, this is probably a problem with PHP version since this line uses a new syntax introduced in PHP 7.1